# Is it possible to delete duplicate documents after they are indexed?

Tags: elasticsearch

Our log processing went a bit haywire and we ended up with 2-5 copies of some logs in our ElasticSearch cluster. Fortunately, each one has a md5 hash stored with it in an indexed field (which is its own problem, but for another day).

So, in theory, we should be able to delete all by one copy of every document by using that field. However, I can't figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?